# Dynamic, conditional comparison of object

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-statements

I'm working on a system to do comparison between a condition and an object (or array of objects) and am trying to find the best way to handle it. For example, the 'query' looks like this:

```
var query = {
  field: 'name',
  operand: '==',
  value: 'Joe'
}
```

Then the array which I'm looping over looks like this:

```
var data = [
  {
    id: 12345,
    name: 'John'
  },{
    id: 67890,
    name: 'Joe'
  }
]
```

Then I just loop over and want to only `push` into `results` the matches:

```
var results = [];
for (var i=0, z=data.length; i<z; i++) {
  // In here, evaluate current iterative object against query...
  // on match - results.push(data[i]);
}
```

I am thinking I could use `eval` on a string derived from the `query` properties, but wondering if there's a better approach I'm just not seeing.

Comment: A simple `if` condition? `if (query.operator == '==') { return data[0][query.field] == data[1][query.field] }`

Comment: The `operand` can change, for instance if I want to check for values `>=` some number I need the operand property to set that evaluation method.